# Response stuck when creating contract

Tags: web3js, ether, nodejs

I am creating a contract on my local blockchain network using web3. On my node , contact is created and address is generated. But on node application, response is struck.

Here is my node code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://192.168.56.103:8000"))
//const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const compiledFactory = require('./ethereum/build/CampaignFactory.json')

const deploy = async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    console.log(accounts)

    addr = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount('123456');
    console.log(addr)

    factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
    .deploy({ data: '0x' + compiledFactory.bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

    console.log(factory)
}

deploy();
```

Here is console from node app that is stuck after

```
[ '0xDa8512CBD5c5eaa1213e5A7bEefAf35e9bA2c9EA',
  '0x3F5dD664F0A803d546E087Ee03B69aEb97D428DB',
  '0x7Eb0390DbF70147f37459F5d982456527FdBdb98',
  '0xD9FcDA95002A09d7be394F085fAEC2a1f3d28476' ]
0x2Cc72882b17960e07FCeF04E54A397628075654D
```

and here is the logs from node:

```
INFO [08-09|03:28:10.027] Submitted contract creation              fullhash=0x63ac15fcc23f19aa44cd225dbacf7ea30069d3e106987daf63a4238caab4b73c contract=0x31F82590e051A224e7d8d63eB54f434d6073aB06
```

Can anybody help? Why I am not getting address on nodejs application?

Comment: do you have balance on that account which will deploy the contract?!

Comment: Yes account have balance. Contract is deployed also. But waiting for response in nodejs application.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of my deploy scripts. Feel free to modify it as needed.

Code which deploys a smart contract | deploy.js

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://192.168.56.103:8000"))

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
      .deploy( { data:bytecode })
      .send( { gas: '5000000', from:accounts[0] });

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Code which compiles smart contract code (creates interface and bytecode) | compile.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Contract.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Contract'];
```

Contract path needs to contain the path to the smart contract .sol file.
In module.exports `.contracts[':Contract'];` the :Contract needs to be replaced with the name of the contract.

In case you need further information just ask.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using test net from another provider like rinkeby or etc. process for deploy a contract took little longer for getting return value. approximately 6-8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the return value `factory` is, so dumping it on the console
may be blank if it's undefined. When you say it is hanging,
do you mean your NodeJS application never completes, or just that it prints
nothing after the list of addresses?

In any case, as you say, it seems like just a display problem, not a contract deploying problem. You can add another `console.log('Done')` line after `console.log(factory)`,
or even `console.log(JSON.stringify(factory))`, to make sure the script is actually completing.

Usually `truffle` or `web3` methods like to return a transaction hash from
methods that send transactions to the blockchain, such as
`0x63ac15fcc23f19aa44cd225dbacf7ea30069d3e106987daf63a4238caab4b73c` in your
example above, but I've never used the `deploy` and `send` methods above.

Comment: Yes it is hanging. Nodejs application never completes it. I added logs like `done` below, but the code execution struck on contract creation.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem when deploying locally to a Hardhat development node. Everything seemed to work fine when I didn't wait for the deployment to complete (or if I deployed to a live network).

To fix the issue, I set `autoMine: true` in my deployment request and things started working just fine.